# How to fix the NAN or INF when we use cross entropy with theano?

Tags: machine-learning, theano

We'll have to compute:

`y*log(y_compute)+(1-y)*(1-y_compute)`

so when we get `y_compute` **1**. or **0**.，this problem would show up. What should I do to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression `y_compute` maybe contains an exponential, e.g. coming from `theano.tensor.nnet.sigmoid`? In that case, it should usually never reach exact 0 or 1. In those cases you can then just use your expression or `theano.tensor.nnet.crossentropy_categorical_1hot` directly.

If for whatever reason you have exact 0 and 1, another way is to clip the input to the crossentropy. Try e.g. replacing `y_compute` with `theano.tensor.clip(y_compute, 0.001, 0.999)`, knowing that this will restrict the range of the logarithm.

Comment: Thank you. I used theano.tensor.nnet.sigmoid and I found that if x > 20 then y will be equal to 1. so theano.tensor.clip will be a good solution.

Comment: I think that situation is to be avoided in general. Can you make it not happen like that? The clipping may not work if you have other problems that come before.

Comment: Yeah, I know, sometimes because of bad initialization or large learning rate or wrong target function etc. Thank you!